# The real sense of list generators in haskell

Tags: haskell

As I understand, the code

```
l = [(a,b)|a<-[1,2],b<-[3,4]]
```

is equivalent to

```
l = do
  a <- [1,2]
  b <- [3,4]
  return (a,b)
```

or

```
[1,2] >>= (\a -> [3,4] >>= (\b -> return (a,b)))
```

The type of such expression is [(t,t1)] where t and t1 are in Num.

If I write something like

```
getLine >>= (\a -> getLine >>= (\b -> return (a,b)))
```

the interpreter reads two lines and returns a tuple containing them.

But can I use getLine or something like that in list generators?

The expression

```
[x|x<-getLine]
```

returns an error "Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type`IO String'"

But, of course, this works in do-notation or using (>>=).

What's the point of list generators, and what's the actual difference between them and do-notation?

Is there any type restriction when using list gens?

Answer (score 9):

That's a sensible observation, and you're not the first one to stumble upon that. You're right that the translation of `[x|x<-getLine]` would lead to a perfectly valid monadic expression. The point is that list comprehensions were, I think, [first](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.11) only introduced as convenience syntax for lists, and (probably) no one thought that people might use them for other monads.

However, since the restriction to `[]` is not really a necessary one, there is a GHC extension called [`-XMonadComprehensions`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#monad-comprehensions) which removes the restriction and allows you to write exactly what you wanted:

```
Prelude> :set -XMonadComprehensions 
Prelude> [x|x<-getLine]
sdf
"sdf"
```

Comment: I hear rumors that comprehensions *used to* work for any monad, but the error messages were incomprehensible, so it was changed. I don't have a cite for that though...

Comment: Well, that would make sense if in the olde days, the translation was purely rewriting and independent from type checking... maybe before someone rigourosly applied what stands in the report.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: There's [this ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4370) and [this wiki page](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/MonadComprehensions); both indicate that MonadComprehensions were originally allowed, then removed, and later added back via the language extension.

Comment: @Zeta ...so it was in Haskell 1.4. I was hoping I hadn't imagined it... :)

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that list comprehensions can *only* be used to construct *lists*.

*However*, there's a language extension called "monad comprehensions" that allows you to use any arbitrary monad.

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/MonadComprehensions